# Importing Gradle project with "Use gradle wrapper with verification" immediately failing in Android Studio 0.2.9

Tags: gradle, android-studio

*NOTE: i figured out the solution to this as i was writing the post, but i'll put the info up here in case anyone else needs it.*

Android Studio was giving me the following error when i tried to import a Gradle project (using `File` -> `Import Project...` and selecting the `build.gradle` file)

```
Resolve Error

Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://
services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots/
gradle-1.8-20130830160653+0000-bin.zip'.
java.util.zip.ZipException: error in opening zip file
error in opening zip file

Consult IDE log for more details (Help | Show Log)
```

see also:

- [Screenshot of error dialog](https://i.stack.imgur.com/LPMs1.png)
- [gist of error log](https://gist.github.com/nrser/29adf615599691baf36d)

the error appeared immediately after clicking 'OK' in the import dialog. the import process had previously failed due to a spotty internet connection, and i guessed that Android Studio / Gradle may have cached the partial download and was now unsuccessfully trying to use that partial download instead of fetching the files.

## solution

this issue can be resolved by clearing the bad download out of the cache. my cache on OSX for `gradle-1.8-20130830160653+0000-bin.zip` was located at

```
~/.gradle/wrapper/dists/gradle-1.8-20130830160653+0000-bin
```

removing that directory and retrying the 'Import Project from Gradle' process again promoted the system to retry the download.

hope this helps someone spend less time on this than i did :)

Answer (score 0):

For Windows users it is located in

> C:\Users\%your_username%\.gradle\wrapper\dists

just remove everything inside the above folder...

Hope it helps... :)

Answer (score 0):

In eclise go to Window>preferences>Gradle.

in Gradle distribuition check URL

Put the value choosing the your distribuition from 
https://services.gradle.org/distributions-snapshots

Sorry my bad english XD