# Android Studio - error in opening file

Tags: android, ubuntu, android-studio, android-gradle-plugin, build.gradle

I've just installed Ubuntu 14.04. I had an android studio project saved on Ubuntu One.
If I create a new project, android studio works fine, but if I import that project I get:

```
Gradle 'MyProject' project refresh failed:
     Cause: error in opening zip file
     Gradle settings
```

My log starts with:

```
2014-03-29 15:06:41,518 [ 323947]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 
2014-03-29 15:06:41,522 [ 323951]   INFO - s.plugins.gradle.GradleManager - Instructing gradle to use java from /usr/lib/jvm/java-1.7.0-openjdk-amd64 
2014-03-29 15:06:41,526 [ 323955]   WARN - .project.GradleExecutionHelper - can not get BuildEnvironment model 
org.gradle.tooling.GradleConnectionException: Could not install Gradle distribution from 'http://services.gradle.org/distributions/gradle-1.11-all.zip'.
```

[full log from start of android studio](http://pastebin.com/kAL759T3)

Comment: Have you tried deleting the zip from your gradle cache? http://stackoverflow.com/questions/18953432/importing-gradle-project-with-use-gradle-wrapper-with-verification-immediately

Comment: You can try building from the command line and see if it gives you any more information.

Comment: Enirco you're right, thanks. I tried it before but it didn't work cause I didn't restart android studio

Answer (score 0):

Make sure first that you can build your project on the command line:

```
./gradlew assembleDebug
```

This assumes that you have `./gradlew` and the `gradle/` directory.

If the above works, then you should be able to import the project into Android Studio by following these steps:

- Click **Open Project**
- Navigate to the project directory and select `settings.gradle`
- Accept the default choice of **Use default gradle wrapper (recommended)**